# Ubuntu 16.04 Shutdown freeze Asus

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

Until now none of the QuestionsI found here work, so I hope someone can help me with the problem I have.

Hardware:
Asus Laptop
Processor Intel® Core™ i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 64 bit
RAM 7,7GiB
Graphics Geforce GTX950M

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS // Windows 10

After installing I had the problem that shortly after booting the system was useless due to thousands of flashing messages (PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected). After selecting the X.org driver for graphics this didn't occur anymore. But as I soon noticed the shutdown doesn't work anymore. 
I tried the following:

```
klicking on the shutdown icon
sudo swapoff -a && systemctl poweroff
sudo shutdown now
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Result: freeze

/etc/default/grub
I edited to this (and did sudo update-grub):
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nomsi acpi=force apm=power_off"

/etc/systemd/system.conf
I tried 
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=10s
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s
and 5s and then sudo systemctl daemon-reload.

For a while this seemed to help but now it freezes again.

WHat exactly can I do to fix it? I don't think that doing a hard reset all the time is beneficial to the hardware ...

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

syslog shows this for klicking on shutdown:

> Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC gnome-session[1650]:
>   gnome-session-binary[1650]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref:
>   assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC
>   gnome-session-binary[1650]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref:
>   assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC
>   gnome-session[1650]: gnome-session-binary[1650]:
>   GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT
>   (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC gnome-session-binary[1650]:
>   GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT
>   (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC gnome-session[1650]:
>   gnome-session-binary[1650]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref:
>   assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC
>   gnome-session-binary[1650]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref:
>   assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC
>   gnome-session[1650]: gnome-session-binary[1650]:
>   GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT
>   (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC gnome-session-binary[1650]:
>   GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT
>   (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC gnome-session[1650]:
>   gnome-session-binary[1650]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref:
>   assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC
>   gnome-session-binary[1650]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref:
>   assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC
>   gnome-session[1650]: gnome-session-binary[1650]:
>   GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT
>   (object)' failed Sep 13 07:50:12 yureikoPC gnome-session-binary[1650]:
>   GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT
>   (object)' failed

and this for `shutdown -h now`

> Sep 13 07:54:08 yureikoPC systemd[1]: Stopping Authenticate and
>   Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks... Sep 13 07:54:08 yureikoPC
>   systemd[1]: Stopping Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
>   Sep 13 07:54:08 yureikoPC systemd[1]: Stopping Save/Restore Sound Card
>   State... Sep 13 07:54:08 yureikoPC systemd[1]: Stopped Stop ureadahead
>   data collection 45s after completed startup. Sep 13 07:54:08 yureikoPC
>   systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.

both are followed by rows of \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\

System updates also don't seem to work. There are 2 updates available to the system and installing them results in a permanent "installation in progress"